# Deploying Elastic search 6 in Azure Container Instance

Tags: azure, docker, elasticsearch

I'm trying to deploy the current version of Elastic Search in an Azure Container Instance using the Docker image, however, I need to set `vm.max_map_count=262144`. Although since the container continually tries to restart on `max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]` I can't hit the instance with any commands. Trying to disable restarts or continuing on Errors causes the container instance to fail.

Comment: Do you try to use the command [`az container exec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-exec) to execute the shell script in the container?

Comment: Yea I tried using the command `az container exec --resource-group <group-name> --name <container-group-name> --exec-command "sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144"` in the Azure shell, but because of the instance is in a restart loop I'm not sure if the command is being accepted properly.

Comment: After submitting the command it also continues to restart

Comment: You just can execute the command when the container instance in the running state and without interaction. And I suggest you recreate the image of the container instance. It's the best way.

Comment: When I run the command it either does nothing and the instance fails and restarts as usual or I get this error: `rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144\": executable file not found in $PATH"`. Am I running the correct script?

Comment: I suggest you check the image if it can work well locally. The error seems that there is something wrong in your image.

Comment: I got it to deploy, I had to make my own image and alter the elasicsearch .yml to include `discovery: type: single-node`. This makes elasticsearch only throw a warning instead of an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments it sounds like you may have resolved the issue. In general for future readers a possible troubleshooting guide is:

If container exits unsuccessfully

1. Try using EXEC for interactive debugging while container is running. This can be found in the Azure portal as well on the "Containers" tab.
2. Attempt to run to success on local docker if EXEC did not help.
3. Upload new container version after local success was found to your registry and try to redeploy to ACI.

If container exits successfully and repeatedly restarts

1. Verify you have a long-running command for the container.
2. Update the restart policy to Never so upon exit you can debug the terminated container group.
3. If you cannot find issues, follow the local steps and get a successful run with local Docker.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please have a look at this article - https://www.garyjackson.dev/posts/azure-container-instance-dns-private-ip/